# I'm trying to use stripe payment. But having some issues on submitting card details

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

Im following just django tutorial. I'm unable to get any success message or error message after clicking submit button. the page is not even getting redirected after clicking submit button. dont know where i went wrong with my post method. P.s. Ive created my stripe acc and Ive used those public and private keys. Any help is appreciated. TIA

**payment.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <main class="mt-5 pt-4">
    <div class="container wow fadeIn">

      <h2 class="my-5 h2 text-center">Payment</h2>

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">

          <div class="card">

              <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

                <form action="." method="post" id="stripe-form">
                {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="stripe-form-row">
                    <label for="card-element" id="stripeBtnLabel">
                        Credit or debit card
                    </label>
                    <div id="card-element" class="StripeElement StripeElement--empty"><div class="__PrivateStripeElement" style="margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; border: medium none !important; display: block !important; background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0% !important; position: relative !important; opacity: 1 !important;"><iframe allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" name="__privateStripeFrame5" allowpaymentrequest="true" src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/elements-inner-card-fbfeb5b62d598125b16ab6addef894d6.html#style[base][color]=%2332325d&amp;style[base][fontFamily]=%22Helvetica+Neue%22%2C+Helvetica%2C+sans-serif&amp;style[base][fontSmoothing]=antialiased&amp;style[base][fontSize]=16px&amp;style[base][::placeholder][color]=%23aab7c4&amp;style[invalid][color]=%23fa755a&amp;style[invalid][iconColor]=%23fa755a&amp;componentName=card&amp;wait=false&amp;rtl=false&amp;keyMode=test&amp;apiKey=pk_test_i0vc3rYRd3tcPmIsJIIQOiiI00khWr20iQ&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fstripe.com&amp;referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fstripe.com%2Fdocs%2Fstripe-js&amp;controllerId=__privateStripeController1" title="Secure payment input frame" style="border: medium none !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; width: 1px !important; min-width: 100% !important; overflow: hidden !important; display: block !important; height: 19.2px;" frameborder="0"></iframe><input class="__PrivateStripeElement-input" aria-hidden="true" aria-label=" " autocomplete="false" maxlength="1" style="border: medium none !important; display: block !important; position: absolute !important; height: 1px !important; top: 0px !important; left: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important; width: 100% !important; opacity: 0 !important; background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0% !important; pointer-events: none !important; font-size: 16px !important;"></div></div>
                    <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
                    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
                    </div>

                    <button id="stripeBtn">Submit Payment</button>
                </form>

          </div>
          <!--/.Card-->

        </div>
        <!--Grid column-->

      </div>
      <!--Grid row-->

    </div>
  </main>

    {% endblock content %}

    {% block extra_scripts %} 
<script type="text/javascript" nonce="zQL2oP9DrQhQ+sjXkd3Usg==">  // Create a Stripe client.
  var stripe = Stripe('acc key');
  var elements = stripe.elements();
  var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});
  card.mount('#card-element');
  card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
  });
  var form = document.getElementById('stripe-form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {

        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      } else {

        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
      }
    });
  });


  function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    var form = document.getElementById('stripe-form');
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    // Submit the form
    form.submit();
  }

  var successElement = document.getElementById('stripe-token-handler');
  document.querySelector('.wrapper').addEventListener('click', function() {
    successElement.className = 'is-hidden';
  });

  function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
    successElement.className = '';
    successElement.querySelector('.token').textContent = token.id;
  }
</script>
    {% endblock extra_scripts %}
```

**views.py**

```
class PaymentView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("get mothod")
        return render(self.request, "payment.html")

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("post method")
        order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
        token = self.request.POST.get('stripeToken')
        amount=order.get_total_price()
        print(self.user.POST)


        try:
            print("try loop")
            # Use Stripe's library to make requests...
            charge = stripe.Charge.create(
                amount=amount,
                currency="inr",
                source=token            )

                #create paymeny
            payment = Payment()
            payment.stripe_charge_id = charge['id']
            payment.amount = amount
            payment.save()

            #assign payment to order
            order.odered = True
            order.payment = payment
            order.save()

            messages.success(self.request, "payment successful")
            return redirect("/")


        except stripe.error.CardError as e:
            # Since it's a decline, stripe.error.CardError will be caught
            body = e.json_body
            err = body.get('error', {})
            messages.warning(self.request, f"{err.get('message')}")
            return redirect("/")


        except stripe.error.RateLimitError as e:
                # Too many requests made to the API too quickly
                messages.error(self.request, f"{err.get('message')}")
                return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.InvalidRequestError as e:
                # Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
                messages.error(self.request,"invalid parameters")
                return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.AuthenticationError as e:
            # Authentication with Stripe's API failed
            # (maybe you changed API keys recently)
                messages.error(self.request, "not authenticated")
                return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.APIConnectionError as e:
            # Network communication with Stripe failed
                messages.error(self.request, "no network")
                return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.StripeError as e:
            # Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
            # yourself an email
                messages.error(self.request, "soemthng went wrong")
                return redirect("/")

        except Exception as e:
            # Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
                messages.error(self.request, "soemthing went wrong. we re notified")
                return redirect("/")
```

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages in your browser console?

Comment: Yes. Type error:successelement is null. And for the first time when payment form loads i get type error document query selector null. But i do get a api token in response from stripe

Comment: You don't have an element called `stripe-token-handler` in the HTML.  What's the actual error/issue you're having?  What's not working exactly, and what have you tried?

Comment: @floatingLomas after submitting card details. I'm not getting any success message or error message. which im suppose to get and get redirected to homepage. but none is happening. Im not where i went wrong. i do have used strip token handler in js.

Comment: @SaketMarwad You should check the console of the browser for errors; it's possible something's happening there.  Also you're POSTing to the same page as the Javascript is running on; is that what you intend to do?